# How to implement a scheduler using QUARTZ on an ASP.NET Web API Core application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, quartz-scheduler

I am currently developing a Web API that processes appointments and recurring events. I found quartz-scheduler.net that would be appropriate but the problem is that it is not compatible with asp.NET Core version.

Is there a way to implement quartz.NET to asp.NET core or is there some kind of replacement or alternative?

Answer (score 3):

Quartz.NET 3.0 Alpha 1 Released: supports .NET Core / netstandard 1.3.
see more in this [announcement](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/2016/08/16/quartznet-3.0-alpha1-released.html).

You can monitor the progress in this ticket: [Support for .NET Core or vNext #355](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/issues/355)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it following these steps:

1. Created .NET Core Service Extension (QuartzExtension.cs):

   ```
   public static class QuartzExtensions
   {
       public static void UseQuartz(this IApplicationBuilder app)
       {
           app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IScheduler>();
       }

       public static async void AddQuartz(this IServiceCollection services)
       {
           var properties = new NameValueCollection
           {
               // json serialization is the one supported under .NET Core (binary isn't)
               ["quartz.serializer.type"] = "json",

               // the following setup of job store is just for example and it didn't change from v2
               ["quartz.jobStore.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz",
               ["quartz.jobStore.useProperties"] = "false",
               ["quartz.jobStore.dataSource"] = "default",
               ["quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix"] = "QRTZ_",
               ["quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SqlServerDelegate, Quartz",
               ["quartz.dataSource.default.provider"] = "SqlServer-41", // SqlServer-41 is the new provider for .NET Core
               ["quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString"] = @"Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=sta-scheduler-quartz;Integrated Security=true"
           };

           var schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
           var scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler().Result;
           scheduler.Start().Wait();

           services.AddSingleton<IScheduler>(scheduler);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Used it as follow in Startup.cs

   ```
   public class Startup
   {
       public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
       {
           Configuration = configuration;
       }

       public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

       // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
       public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
       {
           services.AddMvc();

           // Authentication service
           JwtAuthentication.AddJwtAuthentication(services);

           services.AddQuartz(); // <======== THIS LINE

           services.AddSingleton<IHttpRequestScheduler, HttpRequestScheduler>();
       }

       // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
       public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, 
                             IHostingEnvironment env, 
                             ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
                             IApplicationLifetime lifetime)
       {
           if (env.IsDevelopment())
           {
               app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
           }

           app.UseMvc();

           app.UseAuthentication();

           // Add JWT generation endpoint:
           var options = new TokenProviderOptions
           {
               Audience = "ExampleAudience",
               Issuer = "ExampleIssuer",
               SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(JwtAuthentication.SIGNING_KEY, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256),
           };

           app.UseMiddleware<TokenProviderMiddleware>(Options.Create(options));

           app.UseQuartz(); // <======== THIS LINE
       }
   }
   ```
3. Now whenever I want to use the scheduler object I can get it with DependecyInjection, like this example:

   ```
   public class HttpRequestScheduler : IHttpRequestScheduler
   {
       private IScheduler _scheduler;

       public HttpRequestScheduler(IScheduler scheduler)
       {
           _scheduler = scheduler;
       }

       public void Schedule()
       {
           // Whatever you want to do with the scheduler
           ...
       }
   }
   ```

PS1: Everything I used was obtained from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42199592/3891823) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43058170/3891823).

PS2: Do not forget to create your localdb database and populate it following the scripts given by quartznet [here](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/tree/master/database/tables)