# Quartz.Net Dependency Injection .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, scheduler, quartz.net

In my project I have to use Quartz but I don't know what i do wrong.

JobFactory:

```cs
public class IoCJobFactory : IJobFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _factory;

    public IoCJobFactory(IServiceProvider factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }
    public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        return _factory.GetService(bundle.JobDetail.JobType) as IJob;
    }

    public void ReturnJob(IJob job)
    {
        var disposable = job as IDisposable;
        if (disposable != null)
        {
            disposable.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

QuartzExtensions:

```cs
public static class QuartzExtensions
{
    public static void UseQuartz(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IScheduler>();
    }

    public static async void AddQuartz(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var props = new NameValueCollection
        {
            {"quartz.serializer.type", "json"}
        };
        var factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(props);
        var scheduler = await factory.GetScheduler();

        var jobFactory = new IoCJobFactory(services.BuildServiceProvider());
        scheduler.JobFactory = jobFactory;
        await scheduler.Start();
        services.AddSingleton(scheduler);
    }
}
```

And when I try run my Job (class have dependency injection) i always get Exception becouse:

```
_factory.GetService(bundle.JobDetail.JobType) as IJob;
```

is always null.

My class implement `IJob` and in startup.cs I add:

```cs
services.AddScoped<IJob, HelloJob>();
services.AddQuartz();
```

and

```
app.UseQuartz();
```

I using standard .net Core dependency injection:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
```

Comment: Did you installed your Jobs in your DI?

Comment: Ye i have only one job so i installed it by `services.AddScoped<IJob, HelloJob>();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I did it in my application. Instead of adding the Scheduler to the ioc I only add the factory

```
services.AddTransient<IJobFactory, AspJobFactory>(
                (provider) =>
                {
                    return new AspJobFactory( provider );
                } );
```

My job factory pretty much looks the same. Transient does not really matter as I only use this once anyway. My use Quartz extension method then is

```
public static void UseQuartz(this IApplicationBuilder app, Action<Quartz> configuration)
        {
            // Job Factory through IOC container
            var jobFactory = (IJobFactory)app.ApplicationServices.GetService( typeof( IJobFactory ) );
            // Set job factory
            Quartz.Instance.UseJobFactory( jobFactory );

            // Run configuration
            configuration.Invoke( Quartz.Instance );
            // Run Quartz
            Quartz.Start();
        }
```

The `Quartz` class is Singleton as well.

Comment: `Quartz.Instance` is in my excample `scheduler` ? And `Action<Quartz>` what is it? becouse `Quartz` in my app "Quartz is a namespace but is used like a type"

Comment: `Quartz` is a custom class I made. Here is the code https://gist.github.com/Mats391/50cbf7f9c0291e623565dd0cc1baace3

Comment: You are very helpful. Can You tell me in your startup.cs you don't use `services.AddQuartz();` ? And `UseQuartz` need to have configuration so how you add this in your Startup.cs?

Comment: Here is the Quartz related stuff from my Startup.cs [link](https://gist.github.com/Mats391/adf04090990012ba788cb086817c770f)

Comment: @donex93 I do not understand. On the `Quartz` you can add and remove jobs as you please. For my purposes I never need to remove jobs, so I did not bother with that.

Comment: I have one more problem: My application after few minutes stoped. I dont know why? I read article about .net core and .net core application should not stop - it is always running. I log my quartz and I saw: https://wklej.to/K2Enu every some time. And after that my scheduled jobs are removed from the queue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135600/discussion-between-mats391-and-donex93).

Answer (score 8):

This is just a simple sample of my solution to solve IoC problem:

*JobFactory.cs*

```
public class JobFactory : IJobFactory
    {
        protected readonly IServiceProvider Container;

        public JobFactory(IServiceProvider container)
        {
            Container = container;
        }

        public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
        {
            return Container.GetService(bundle.JobDetail.JobType) as IJob;
        }

        public void ReturnJob(IJob job)
        {
            (job as IDisposable)?.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

*Startup.cs*

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, 
            IHostingEnvironment env, 
            ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
            IApplicationLifetime lifetime,
            IServiceProvider container)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            app.UseMvc();

            // the following 3 lines hook QuartzStartup into web host lifecycle
            var quartz = new QuartzStartup(container);
            lifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(quartz.Start);
            lifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(quartz.Stop);
        }
```

*QuartzStartup.cs*

```
public class QuartzStartup
    {
        private IScheduler _scheduler; // after Start, and until shutdown completes, references the scheduler object
        private readonly IServiceProvider container;

        public QuartzStartup(IServiceProvider container)
        {
            this.container = container;
        }

        // starts the scheduler, defines the jobs and the triggers
        public void Start()
        {
            if (_scheduler != null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Already started.");
            }

            var schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
            _scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler().Result;
            _scheduler.JobFactory = new JobFactory(container);
            _scheduler.Start().Wait();

            var voteJob = JobBuilder.Create<VoteJob>()
                .Build();

            var voteJobTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .StartNow()
                .WithSimpleSchedule(s => s
                    .WithIntervalInSeconds(60)
                    .RepeatForever())
                .Build();

            _scheduler.ScheduleJob(voteJob, voteJobTrigger).Wait();
        }

        // initiates shutdown of the scheduler, and waits until jobs exit gracefully (within allotted timeout)
        public void Stop()
        {
            if (_scheduler == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            // give running jobs 30 sec (for example) to stop gracefully
            if (_scheduler.Shutdown(waitForJobsToComplete: true).Wait(30000))
            {
                _scheduler = null;
            }
            else
            {
                // jobs didn't exit in timely fashion - log a warning...
            }
        }
    }
```

consider that you should register your service into the container (in my case VoteJob) in advance.
I implement this based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43058170/428061).
I hope it can be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

I got the same issue.

I update from

`services.AddScoped<IJob, HelloJob>();`

to

`services.AddScoped<HelloJob>();`

then it works.

`_factory.GetService(bundle.JobDetail.JobType) as IJob;` will not be null :)

Answer (score 1):

Quartz.NET 3.1 will include official support for Microsoft DI and ASP.NET Core Hosted Services.

You can find the revisited packages as:

- [Quartz.Extensions.DependencyInjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Quartz.Extensions.DependencyInjection/) - Microsoft DI integration
- [Quartz.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Quartz.AspNetCore) - ASP.NET Core integration

The best resource the see the new DI integration in progress is to head to [the example ASP.NET Core application](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/tree/master/src/Quartz.Examples.AspNetCore).

https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/2020/07/08/quartznet-3-1-beta-1-released/